# jQuery $(window).scroll event handler off but still firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, squarespace

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with a jQuery plugin that I wrote. Basically, the plugin makes a sidebar element stick to the top of the browser window when scrolling through the blog post that the sidebar belongs to. This should only happen when the window reaches a certain size (768px) or above (the plugin detects this by checking the float style of the sidebar).

Everything works as expected...until you resize the browser from large -- sidebar is sticky -- to small -- sidebar should not be sticky. My onResize function supposedly removes the scroll event handler and only adds it back if the startQuery is true (so, if the sidebar float value is something other than none). I've double and triple checked through the console: everything is working correctly as far as I can tell. I even added `console.log('scroll')` to the onScroll function and it doesn't show up when the event handler is supposed to be removed, but my sidebar is *still* turning sticky when I scroll through the blog posts.

You can see the problem in action [here](http://www.magnoliahousestyled.com/blog). To recreate the steps:

1. Resize your browser window to less than 768px wide and visit the page. See that the .share-bar element inside each blog post does not move as you scroll. 'scroll' is not logged in the console.
2. Resize your browser window to 768px or larger. See that the .share-bar element becomes sticky as you scroll through each blog post, then sticks to the bottom of the post as you scroll past it. 'scroll' is logged in the console.
3. Resize your browser window to less than 768px. See that the .share-bar element becomes sticky as you scroll through each blog post. 'scroll' is not logged in the console.

It's almost as if the event handler is removed, but the elements aren't updating or something. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, but I've researched and tried all sorts of fixes for `$(window).scroll` event problems and none of them are working here.

My call to plugin:

```
$('.share-bar').stickySides({ 
    'wrapper': '.post-wrapper', 
    'content': '.entry-content' });
```

Plugin code:

```
;( function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

var settings;
var throttled;

$.fn.stickySides = function( options ) {

    settings = $.extend( {}, $.fn.stickySides.defaults, options );

    // Store sidebars
    settings.selector = this.selector;
    settings.startQuery = '$("' + settings.selector + '").css(\'float\') != \'none\'';

    // Create debounced resize function
    var debounced = _.debounce( $.fn.stickySides.onResize, settings.wait );
    $(window).resize( debounced );

    // Create throttled scroll function
    throttled = _.throttle( $.fn.stickySides.onScroll, settings.wait );
    // Only continue if the start query is true
    if ( eval(settings.startQuery) == true ) {
        $(window).on( 'scroll.stickySides', throttled );    
    }

    return this;
};

// Define default settings
$.fn.stickySides.defaults = {
    wrapper: 'body',
    content: '.content',
    wait: 100,
    startQuery: ''
};

$.fn.stickySides.onResize = function ( ) {

    $(window).off( 'scroll.stickySides' );

    // Only continue if the start query is true
    if ( eval(settings.startQuery) == true ) {

        $(window).on( 'scroll.stickySides', throttled );

    } else {

        var sides = $(settings.selector);
        sides.each ( function () {

            var elem = $(this);
            var content = elem.siblings( settings.content );

            if ( elem.css('position') == 'fixed' || elem.css('position') == 'absolute' ) {
                elem.css( 'position', 'static' );
            }

            if ( content.css('margin-left') != '0px' ) {
                content.css( 'margin-left', 0 );
            }

        });

    }

};

$.fn.stickySides.onScroll = function ( ) {

    console.log('scroll');      
    var sides = $(settings.selector);

    // Check each sidebar
    sides.each ( function () {

        var elem = $(this);
        var content = elem.siblings( settings.content );
        var wrapper = elem.closest( settings.wrapper );

        var elemHeight = elem.height();
        var wrapperHeight = wrapper.height();

        // Only continue if the wrapper is taller than the sidebar 
        if ( elemHeight >= wrapperHeight ) {

            return;

        } else {

            var wrapperFracs = wrapper.fracs(function (fracs) {

                // Only continue if the wrapper is in view
                if ( fracs.visible == 0 ) {

                    return;

                } else {

                    // Check if the wrapper extends beyond the top of
                    // the viewport
                    var wrapperSpaceTop = fracs.rects.element.top;

                    // If it does, change sidebar position as appropriate
                    if ( wrapperSpaceTop > 0 ) {

                        var visibleWrapper = fracs.rects.document.height;

                        // If the visible portion of the wrapper is smaller
                        // than the height of the sidebar...
                        if ( visibleWrapper <= elemHeight ) {

                            // ...position the sidebar at the bottom
                            // of the wrapper
                            if ( wrapperSpaceTop != 0 ) {

                                elem.css('position', 'absolute').css( 'top', (wrapperHeight - elemHeight) + content.position().top + 'px' );

                            } 

                        // Otherwise, move sidebar to appropriate position
                        } else {

                            elem.css('position', 'fixed').css('top', 0);

                        }

                        content.css('margin-left', elem.outerWidth());

                    } else {

                        elem.css('position', 'static');
                        content.css('margin-left', 0);

                    }

                }
            });


        }


    });

};

} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

PS: I would use an existing plugin, but I didn't see one that got really close to the functionality I need here; feel free to point one out if you know of one. I haven't tested outside of Mac yet. And yes, I know some of the page elements don't flow very well on mobile -- ex: site header & nav -- and there are some other missing items unrelated to this problem. I'm waiting for some feedback from my client before I can address that.

Answer (score 1):

Happens every time. Shortly after I ask for help, I figure it out on my own. ;)

The problem was in the fracs function inside the onScroll function. I didn't realize it called its own resize/scroll handlers, so *those* weren't getting unbound when I removed *my* scroll handler. I just reworked the plugin to take advantage of the fracs library's handlers instead of calling my own scroll handler:

```
;( function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

var settings;
var throttled;

$.fn.stickySides = function( options ) {

    settings = $.extend( {}, $.fn.stickySides.defaults, options );

    // Store sidebars
    settings.selector = this.selector;
    settings.startQuery = '$("' + settings.selector + '").css(\'float\') != \'none\'';

    if ( eval( settings.startQuery ) == true ) {

        $.fn.stickySides.doFracs();

    }

    // Create debounced resize function
    var debounced = _.debounce( $.fn.stickySides.onResize, settings.wait );
    $(window).resize( debounced );

    return this;
};

// Define default settings
$.fn.stickySides.defaults = {
    wrapper: 'body',
    content: '.content',
    wait: 100,
    startQuery: ''
};

$.fn.stickySides.doFracs = function ( ) {

    var sides = $(settings.selector);

    // Check each sidebar
    sides.each ( function () {

        var elem = $(this);
        var content = elem.siblings( settings.content );
        var wrapper = elem.closest( settings.wrapper );

        var elemHeight = elem.height();
        var wrapperHeight = wrapper.height();

        // Only continue if the wrapper is taller than the sidebar 
        if ( elemHeight >= wrapperHeight ) {

            return;

        } else {

            var wrapperFracs = wrapper.fracs( $.fn.stickySides.fracsCallback );

        }

    });

}

$.fn.stickySides.unbindFracs = function ( ) {

    var sides = $(settings.selector);

    // Check each sidebar
    sides.each ( function () {

        var elem = $(this);
        var content = elem.siblings( settings.content );
        var wrapper = elem.closest( settings.wrapper );


        if ( elem.css('position') == 'fixed' || elem.css('position') == 'absolute' ) {
            elem.css( 'position', 'static' );
        }

        if ( content.css('margin-left') != '0px' ) {
            content.css( 'margin-left', 0 );
        }

        wrapper.fracs('unbind');

    });

}

$.fn.stickySides.fracsCallback = function ( fracs ) {

    // Only continue if the wrapper is in view
    if ( fracs.visible == 0 ) {

        return;

    } else {

        var wrapper = $(this);
        var elem = wrapper.find(settings.selector);
        var content = elem.siblings( settings.content );

        var elemHeight = elem.height();
        var wrapperHeight = wrapper.height();

        // Check if the wrapper extends beyond the top of
        // the viewport
        var wrapperSpaceTop = fracs.rects.element.top;

        // If it does, change sidebar position as appropriate
        if ( wrapperSpaceTop > 0 ) {

            var visibleWrapper = fracs.rects.document.height;

            // If the visible portion of the wrapper is smaller
            // than the height of the sidebar...
            if ( visibleWrapper <= elemHeight ) {

                // ...position the sidebar at the bottom
                // of the wrapper
                if ( wrapperSpaceTop != 0 ) {

                    elem.css('position', 'absolute').css( 'top', (wrapperHeight - elemHeight) + content.position().top + 'px' );

                } 

            // Otherwise, move sidebar to appropriate position
            } else {

                elem.css('position', 'fixed').css('top', 0);

            }

            content.css('margin-left', elem.outerWidth());

        } else {

            elem.css('position', 'static');
            content.css('margin-left', 0);

        }

    }

}

$.fn.stickySides.onResize = function ( ) {

    // Only continue if the start query is true
    if ( eval(settings.startQuery) == true ) {

        $.fn.stickySides.doFracs();

    } else {

        $.fn.stickySides.unbindFracs();

    }

};


} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

Voila! Problem solved.